# DateFormat return null java

Tags: java, null

I'm confused. I've tried, well I can not assign a null value to projects which have no date. What am i doing wrong?

```
private static String projectDate = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    List<Project> projects;
    if (projects == null || projects.size() == 0) {
    } else {
        for (Project project : projects) {
            try {
                projectDate = formatter.format(project.getLastAnalyzedDate().getTime());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Last Analyzed failed");
            }
            outFile.println("<LastAnalyzed>" + projectDate + "</LastAnalyzed>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is `null`?

Comment: I'm just want to return null. I have value with date, and without date. And I want to get: Windows 8(Last Analyzed: 12/05/2015); Windows 10(Last Analyzed: null);

Comment: Although your problem is not clear, based your comment above I am inclined to believe you are expecting `projectDate` to be null when `project.getLastAnalyzedDate()` returns null and you catch a `NullPointerException` in your catch block. If that is the case `projectDate` will retain its previous value unless you set it to null when `project.getLastAnalyzedDate()` returns null. I would await your confirmation but if that is true you might want to change the way you have handled nulls.

Comment: @Owl Yes, you are right. I want to catch "null". That is, just add catch (NullPointerException e) and all?

Comment: @Owl I solve this issue, but I think it is bad "catch (NullPointerException e) {projectDate=null;}"

Comment: check if `project.getLastAnalyzedDate()` is null. If so, set `projectDate ` to `null` else execute your code `projectDate = formatter.format(project.getLastAnalyzedDate().getTime());`. Remove that `try catch` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot print to file when projectDate is null. It will cause NullPointerException. You should print check if projectDate is null then print out the "null" String.

```
private static String projectDate = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    List<Project> projects;
    if (projects == null || projects.size() == 0) {
    } else {
        for (Project project : projects) {
            try {
                projectDate = formatter.format(project.getLastAnalyzedDate().getTime());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Last Analyzed failed");
            }
    }
    if(projectDate == null) {
            outFile.println("<LastAnalyzed>" + "null" + "</LastAnalyzed>");
    } else {
            outFile.println("<LastAnalyzed>" + projectDate + "</LastAnalyzed>");
    }
}
```

Comment: or use outFile.println("<LastAnalyzed>" + (projectDate == null) ? "null" : projectDate + "</LastAnalyzed>");

Comment: I believe that isn't the issue. You can concatenate `null` to a String.

Comment: Oh sorry! I tested and just like you said. I guess I still have many things to learn :)